# I'm trying to change my coordinate formats in RStudio

Tags: google-maps

So my data entries for Longitude and Latitude look like this:
87010454" "85404107" "86294685" "85545624" "86243217" "86135700"
And I am trying to plot a map of the US and add my data to it using this codes:

```
library(ggmap)
library(RCurl)
library(xlsx)
urlfile<-'http://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/census/Features/tract2zip/MedianZIP-3.xlsx'
destfile<-"census20062010.xlsx"
download.file(urlfile,destfile,mode="wb")
map<-get_map(location='united states', zoom=4, maptype="terrain",source = 'google',color = 'color')
gmap(map) + geom_point( aes(x=LONGITUD, y=LATITUDE, show_guide = TRUE, colour=STATE), data=accident, alpha=.5, na.rm = T) + scale_color_gradient(low="beige", high="blue")
```

However I think the format for this variables is wrong because I am able to get a map, the data won't appear on it though. Is there any way I can change my format in R Studio to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to follow http://amunategui.github.io/ggmap-example/. The file you download contains data by zip code, but no coordinates. In the example, a zip code decoder from R was used, alternatively http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv can be used, which contains lon and lat degrees values.

I'm not sure where you got your values from. They may be pixel coordinates in zoom level 4.

Comment: They could be packed DDMMSSss with positive west longitudes.